# Not Getting Correct Reponse in CURL Soap PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

$length = strlen($requestXml);
    $ch = curl_init($serviceUrl);

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    "SOAPAction: \"https://example.com/PMAPI/example/$action\"",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($requestXml)
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookieFIle.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookieFIle.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);


curl_close($ch);

$xml=  simplexml_load_string($output);
print_r($xml);
```

Output I am Getting:

> 127464347

which is not in xml format. But in View Source The code is in XML format. But It didnt work when I am parsing this output string into xml parser.

output should be in following format which I can see in view-source page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><TopUpRequestResponse xmlns="https://dollarphone.com/PMAPI/PinManager"><TopUpRequestResult><responseCode>1</responseCode><TransId>27464347</TransId></TopUpRequestResult></TopUpRequestResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

When I am trying to access the object. The error is "Trying to get property of non-object".

Please Anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: You seem to go through a lot of trouble with curl. You know there is something like SoapClient, right? http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Yeah I know. But I am facing Authentication problem when I am trying SoapClient as it is NTLM authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
I just removed the  tag from my result. and It works.

```
  $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$output);
        $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

        // converting to XML
        $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Scratch everything I said before.  It is working as it should

`simplexml_load_string` converts an XML string to an object.    You're doing a `print_r` on a  `SimpleXMLElement` object created by `simplexml_load_string()` and it's just printing out the fields in some human readable way.

Your object has a field with the value `TransId` of `27464347`.

Try a `var_dump($xml)` instead of `print_r` and you'll see the object instead of some human-ish representation of it.

I'm unsure exactly, but just guessing the `1` preappended in the string you're seeing from you `print_r` might of it being the first object in the XML body?  Here's a link to the `__toString()` method of the `SimpleXMLElement` http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php

Comment: I can see the namespaces of object but body is empty.

Comment: Add to the post the result of: var_dump($xml);

Comment: object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]

Comment: $xml=  new SimpleXMLElement($output);
    echo $xml->asXML();
    var_dump($xml);
    var_dump($xml->getNamespaces());

Comment: Output:127469690

object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]

array (size=1)
  'soap' => string 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' (length=41)